# amzi prolog + eclipse question

Tags: prolog

hey guys i have a question regarding amzi prolog with eclipse,

Im running a .pro file which executes a breadth first search and if queue gets too long,

the following error message appears:

> system_error 1021 Control stack full.
>   Compile code or increase .cfg
>   parameter 'control'

If so, how may i run the compiled code under eclipse? I've tried running the project but the listener just ends without accepting any queries....?

Comment: @manlio: there is nothing specific in the question to the mentioned systems!

Answer (score 1):

Control stack full means one of two things:

- You have a deep recursion that exhausts the control stack. In that case you need to increase the default value of 'control' in your **amzi.cfg** file. You may find you that have to increase 'heap', 'trail' and/or 'local' as well.
- You have an error in your program causing an **infinite recursion**.

Running the program in the debugger will show you which case you've got. In the **initial** case you will see it digging deeper and deeper for a solution. In the **later** case you will see it chasing it's tail in circles with each recursion the same as the one before, but with different variables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know amzi prolog (I only used SICStus and SWI), and never used Eclipse for prolog, but as the error message says, try compiling (instead of consulting) your code. Look under project/properties for build configurations (like run/deug, as it works for Java/C++). Hopefully, that ".cfg paramerer" can also be accessed through project/properties.